# Building Android app using SIP

Tags: android, sip

I am beginner of SIP, and its usage on Android. I would like to use SIP to build an Android App. I searched some demo App examples, but I couldn't get them very well. I would like to ask that are there any good libraries, and any examples to understand how to build Android Apps using SIP for registering and calling.

Comment: If you are trying to develop a messaging app something like Whatsapp, I would recommend you to use XMPP. There is also a library called ASmack for android to implement it.

Comment: Tesekkurler . No I would like to build app only for calling .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RestComm Android SDK, which does just that and is open source so you can check the code. It provides SIP signalling (JAIN SIP) and webrtc media facilities and exposes them through an easy to use API that your Android Application can use to make/receive calls and send/receive text messages.

You can check the project at GitHub:

https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk

Notice that a full fledged sample Application is also provided in the form of .apk that you can directly install in your Android device to check it out:

https://tsfr.io/qksja4